# Issue with setting up iOS push notifications because AppDelegate.h isn't finding a needed header

Tags: ios, azure, push-notification, azure-api-apps

I'm following instructions for push notification setup for iOS. Instructions can be found here:

```
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-ios-get-started/
```

I am at the step where I must:

```
Open your AppDelegate.h file add the following import directives:

     #import <WindowsAzureMessaging/WindowsAzureMessaging.h> 
     #import "HubInfo.h"
```

However, I get the following error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Shl6U.jpg

Here is my file outline:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/02DU2.jpg

Any idea what I am doing wrong? The mistake is probably very simple. Obviously the Azure header file is present in the header folder, but possibly my syntax is off in some way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you've downloaded your frameworks, you should place it in your project folder.

[image]

After that you should go to **Build Settings** -> **Runpath Search Paths** and add **$(PROJECT_DIR)**

It shows Xcode, where to search for these frameworks

[image]

After all of that you just add them to the Xcode project itself

[image]

Btw, you can place these frameworks anywhere you want, but you should provide a valid search path for Xcode to find them.

Comment: Do you think that I am missing a library? ( Here is my current framework setup: http://imgur.com/26Qvv9I)

Comment: I've figured it out. I will update the answer @user3373665